Cannot use {{.Task.Slot}} as constraints for docker swarm's stack file
I have a docker swarm with 3 replicas for service for which the deploy setup is as follows:
deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 3 
   placement:
     max_replicas_per_node: 1
     constraints:
       - node.hostname == worker-{{.Task.Slot}}

I have 3 workers with hostnames like: worker-1, worker-2 and worker-3 and I want the service.1 to be in worker-1, service.2 to be in worker-2, and so on.
but with the mentioned setup I get the following error:
 Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = value 'worker-{{.Task.Slot}}' is invalid
Any idea what is wrong and what can I do to achieve this?

I wish this worked. Would make stable etcd/minio etc deployments possible with trivial setup.
The only thing you can do with constraints is to turn the problem around by explicitly labelling nodes:
docker node update node1 --label-add "acme.enable=true"
docker node update node2 --label-add "acme.enable=true"

and then, assuming the node's hostname is appropriate, this compose applies:
services:
  acme:
    hostname: {{.Node.Hostname}}
    environment:
      HOST: {{.Node.Hostname}}
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          node.labels.acme.enable: "true"

An alternative to this would be to use node generic resources. This is a system designed to allow devices on nodes to be advertised and claimed using simple text labels.
First, you add the list of "resources" unique to each node in each nodes daemon.json. On the node you want to associate with "host1" you could declare an "ACME_HOST" resource like this:
/etc/docker/deamon.json
{
  "node-generic-resources" : [ "ACME_HOST=host1" ]
}

In your service, you declare that each service task needs 1 instance of an ACME_HOST resource.
compose.yaml
services:
  acme:
    ...
    command: echo $$DOCKER_RESOURCE_ACME_HOST
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          generic_resources:
            - discrete_resource_spec:
                kind: 'ACME_HOST'
                value: 1

Docker will then schedule tasks on nodes that have an available ACME_HOST resource declared and inform the task which instance using DOCKER_RESOURCE_* environment variable.
